# Google Script Exception: Document [spreadsheetID] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I occasionally get the Exception message "Google Script Exception: Document [spreadsheetID] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)".

The script is running on a timed trigger every minute so it is obviously finding the document a lot more than it is not, as the Exception only happens maybe once or twice every few days.  It happens at different times of the day as well. I also get an error "Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets" with not further info.

Comment: Are you the only user with access to the script? The only user with triggers created for that script? Are you using a A1 notation range without specifying the row (i.e: "C2:C")?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always rely on triggers. Something is happening. Errors too.

If you use such a frequent trigger, you can just wrap it all in error checking and forget about it.

```
function myTrigger(){
  try{
    // Trigger's code
  } catch(err){
    if(/Document ABCD12344 is missing/.test(err.message))
      console.warn(err.message, err.stack); // Put it to console. Let it be silent
    else throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```